# how to extract year from different types of date in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, date

I've a column with different types of date such as:

```
2\06\1998
21.11.1998  
18-02-2001
03/05/1999 
20 july 1999
```

I only want the year.

I tried different type of regex such as:

```
def get_date(date):
        number= re.findall('\[0-9]\-{0,1}\\{0,1}\/{0,1}\[0-9]\-{0,1}\\{0,1}\/{0,1}\[0-9]', date)
        return number[6:]
```

but I can't extract the year.
what's the most suitable regex for this case? 
it's not a problem to do two types of regex, one for the format dd/mm/yyyy and one for the date with month in letter.

Comment: `col.str[-4:]` ?

Comment: Try to find a part with 4 digits number like: re.findall(r'\d{4}', date)

Comment: df.col_name.str[-4:]

Comment: @MarkWang Enters `'2019/08/27'`

Comment: @Anup See above

Comment: `re.split(r'\\|\.|-|\/| ', date)[-1]` ?

Comment: Assuming the year is always at the end then `/(\d{4})(?:\s+)?$/gm` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fall into the regex/'strip the last 4 characters' rabbit-hole.
If a date in another format arrives (for example `2019-08-27`) any naive regex/stripping solution will break.

Use `pd.to_datetime` to let pandas deal with the parsing, then just grab `dt.year`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2/06/1998', '21.11.1998', '18-02-2001', '03/05/1999',
                         '20 july 1999', '2019-08-27']})
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
print(df['a'].dt.year)
```

Outputs

```
0    1998
1    1998
2    2001
3    1999
4    1999
5    2019
```

Note: Notice that I had to change the direction of the slashes (`2\06\1998` to `2/06/1998`) but it's a very small price to pay for getting a far more robust solution in return.

Comment: regex solutuion which extract 4-digit number will work on 99% date (not datetime) formats

Comment: @OlvinRoght My solution will work on 100% (as long as the format is standard and not completely arbitrary) and with much less "untested" code

Comment: That's why you've edited source data from post to let it "work on 100%"? :D :D :D

Comment: @OlvinRoght yeah, let's compare a solution that requires you to call `str.replace` to change the direction of slashes **but supports ALL standard date and datetime formats**, to a solution that is using a regex that will break if it gets an unexpected format (even if it is standard)

Comment: Could you provide me date format where regex `\d{4}` will break and pandas not?

Comment: @OlvinRoght `2019-08-27 1000`

Comment: I've noticed twice that it should be date format. And anyway this regex will capture first occurrence which is year.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Today OP only deals with dates, tomorrow OP will have to deal with datetime... My solution saves them another question :)

Comment: thank you @DeepSpace. this seems to me the best solution. I've another question. why in my output the year is float type? 1998.0 for example.

Comment: @IvanMera Not sure, but you can use `.dt.year.astype(int)` or any other equivalent `np` type

Answer (score 2):

I would use simple [`\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/oLQwUg/2) regex.

```
import re

s = """2\\06\\1998
21.11.1998  
18-02-2001
03/05/1999 
20 july 1999"""
for date in s.splitlines():
    year = re.search(r"\d{4}", date).group(0)
    print(year)
```

Comment: The code you wrote was great

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of 2 capturing groups, where in the first group you capture the divider to match a consistent divider for the second one by using a back reference `\1`.

The year part is captured in the second group.

```
^\d+([\\/. -])(?:\d+|[a-z]+)\1(\d{4})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjsjKC/1)

Instead of using anchors `^` and `$` you could use also use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<!\S)\d+([\\/. -])(?:\d+|[a-z]+)\1(\d{4})(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NkLFjY/1)

**Pattern parts**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `([\\/. -])` Capture group 1, match any of the listed
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `|` or
  - `[a-z]+` Match 1+ lowercase chars
- `)` Close non caputring group
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1
- `(\d{4})` Capture group 2, match 4 digits for the year
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) is surprisingly good at recognising different date formats. The only problem it will have is with backslashes, but if you can replace them using string formatting then I think it's easier than using a regex.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2\\06\\1998", "21.11.1998", "18-02-2001", "03/05/1999", "20 july 1999"]})

df["date"] = df["date"].str.replace("\\", "/")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["date"].dt.year

0    1998
1    1998
2    2001
3    1999
4    1999
Name: date, dtype: int64
```